# C# Copy/Move item from listview1 to listview2 with quantity

Tags: c#, listview, copy

I would like to know how do I copy the double-click item from **listview1** to **listview2**, so far I had using this code on **listview1** mouse double click event.

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in lvItemlist.SelectedItems)
        {
            lvItemBuy.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        }
```

When I double click on the item its copy everything about the selected item to my **listview2**, anyway this is not really what i want..lets say in my **listview1** I got this item:

```
ID   |  ITEMNAME | QUANTITY
1    |  ITEM1    | 100
```

What I want is everytime I double-click on the item on **listview1**, the quantity should decrease by 1, so it will be like this on listview1:

```
ID   |  ITEMNAME | QUANTITY
1    |  ITEM1    | 99
```

then added the selected item to **listview2** with 1 quantity like this:

```
ID   |  ITEMNAME | QUANTITY
1    |  ITEM1    | 1
```

After double click again on the same item, it do the same thing on **listview1** but i dont want it to duplicate the item on **listview2**. Simply just +1 the quantity. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do this. You can introduce Id's for the listviewItems. Don't close the ListViewItem direct, instead write a method which copies the properties from the first listviewitem to the second one. In this method you can decrease the quantity and check if the selected listviewitem is already in the second listview

Answer (score 0):

There are two different  different ways.

If you want to copy the items from listview1 to listview2:

```
private static void CopySelectedItems(ListView source, ListView target)
{
    foreach (ListViewItem item in source.SelectedItems)
    {
        target.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
    }
}
```

If you want to move the items from listview1 to listview2:

```
private static void MoveSelectedItems(ListView source, ListView target)
{    
    while (source.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
    {
        ListViewItem temp = source.SelectedItems[0];
        source.Items.Remove(temp);
        target.Items.Add(temp);
    }            
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but that's is not exactly what i want..the copy thing will copy the whole thing including the quantity, so quantity will remain the same on listview1 and listview2..the move thing will remove the entire selected thing from listview1 to listview2