# clone listview from modal form to listview in child form

Tags: c#

i have form1 that is a parent form and form2 that is a child of form1 and form3 is a modal form I open from form2

form2 contains listview1 and form3 contains listview2 .. how to clone items from listview2 to listview1 ?

here's what I have tried :

on modal form form3 :

```
public newpurchase clientFrm;

clientFrm = new newpurchase();
        clientFrm.UpdateListView(this.listView2);
        this.Close();
```

and on child form form2 :

```
public void UpdateListView(ListView listView)
    {
        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView.Items)
        {
            this.listView2.Items.Add((ListViewItem)item.Clone());
        }
    }
```

it doesn't give any error also nothing is copied

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15378486/c-sharp-copy-move-item-from-listview1-to-listview2-with-quantity help?

Comment: it does nothing .. nothing is copied to the form

Comment: What happens if you change `clientFrm = new newpurchase();` to `clientFrm = new newpurchase(); clientFrm.Show();`? How many instances of `newpurchase` are then showing?

Comment: should be only one

Comment: That doesn't appear to be an answer to either of my questions... Did you try my suggestion?

Comment: I tried your suggestion but still the same result nothing is copied and there's only one instance of newpurchase

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use this static method and pass your lists to.

```
 public static void copySourceList(ListView source, ListView target)
 {
     foreach (ListViewItem item in source.Items)
     { 
        ListViewItem temp = (ListViewItem)item.Clone();
        target.Items.Add(temp);
     }
 }
```

I hope it helps you, good luck !

Comment: thanks for the answer but it gives me an error : 

There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'target' of 'newpurchase.copySourceList(ListView, ListView)

Comment: how to fix that ?

Comment: how you call the function ?

Comment: like this : 

    clientFrm.copySourceList(this.listView2);

Comment: you have to pass two lists to function !!!

Comment: like, clientFrm.copySourceList(listView2, listView1);

Comment: this will copy listview2 to listview1

Comment: can you explain plz

Comment: the function requires the two lists (source and target), you should call it with the two lists like i did above.

Comment: now it gives me different error : Member 'newpurchase.copySourceList(ListView, ListView)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead

Comment: it's static method which must be called by name of class not instance !!

Comment: newpurchaseClass.copySourceList(ListView, ListView), newpurchaseClass is name of class

Comment: can you explain please

Comment: do you know what is meaning of static method ?